# Openssl decryption fails when using OCB mode

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl, ocb-mode

I have a PHP library that is a wrapper around Openssl with the goal of making encrypting and decrypting data simpler and secure by default for newer developers. This library successfully handles many different ciphers and modes but I am unable to get OCB mode to work properly.

I am able to encrypt the data seemingly without issue but when I try to decrypt it `openssl_decrypt()` returns `false`. When I check `openssl_error_string()` for any error messages there are none.

Below is a MVCE that demonstrates executing the same code using `AES-128-CBC` and `AES-128-OCB`. The `AES-128-CBC` example works as expected. The `AES-128-OCB` does not with no indication as to why it fails. (I purposely used a plain text string of 16 characters in my example as to remove null padding from the equation).

```
$ciphers = [
    'AES-128-CBC',
    'AES-128-OCB'
];
$key = 'secretkey';
$plainText = 'Testing testing!';

foreach ($ciphers as $cipher) {
    printf('Cipher: %s%s', $cipher, PHP_EOL);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
    printf('IV: %s%s', $iv, PHP_EOL);
    printf('Text: %s%s', $plainText, PHP_EOL);
    $encryptedText = openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    printf('Encrypted Text: %s%s', $encryptedText, PHP_EOL);
    $encodedText = base64_encode($encryptedText);
    printf('Encoded Text: %s%s', $encodedText, PHP_EOL);
    $decodedText = base64_decode($encodedText);
    printf('Decoded Text: %s%s', $decodedText, PHP_EOL);
    $decryptedText = openssl_decrypt($decodedText, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    printf('Decrypted Text: ');
    var_dump($decryptedText);
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string()) {
        printf('Openssl Error: %s%s', $msg, PHP_EOL);
    }
    printf('%s%s', str_repeat('-', 60), PHP_EOL);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Cipher: AES-128-CBC
IV: �K�K�l4.�4;y
Text: Testing testing!
Encrypted Text: vg��~6�D��R�����xd�^�,�[��p"~
Encoded Text: dgUIZ5itfjazRLTiUvzIxsjNeGScXqksjFsaq7pwIn4=
Decoded Text: vg��~6�D��R�����xd�^�,�[��p"~
Decrypted Text: string(16) "Testing testing!"
------------------------------------------------------------
Cipher: AES-128-OCB
IV: ��)����ƢX
Text: Testing testing!
Encrypted Text: m��i��B[�d�
Encoded Text: BW2IkWmo5kJbFgYf8YdkpQ==
Decoded Text: m��i��B[�d�
Decrypted Text: bool(false)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not an expert on encryption but have learned a lot about it while doing this work. I have googled OCB mode and getting it to work with PHP and Openssl and there is virtually nothing out there on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) is an authenticated encryption algorithm like GCM, i.e. during encryption a tag is generated which is used for authentication during decryption. OpenSSL supports OCB ([here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OCB)), whereby the implementation with the high level API is completely equivalent with GCM ([here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Encryption_using_GCM_mode)).

This C code returns the **same** ciphertext as the posted PHP code (assuming the same plaintext, key and nonce). However, the tag generated by the C code is **not generated** by the PHP code. It is neither appended to the ciphertext, nor is it returned in the 6th parameter (`$tag`) as it is for GCM / CCM ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)). The latter even results in an error message (*The authenticated tag cannot be provided for cipher that doesn not support AEAD*).

The PHP bug report [#67304](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67304) from May 2014 filed an identical bug for GCM (tag is not delivered although GCM is in the list of supported algorithms), which then led to the support of GCM and CCM in 7.1. (released December 2016). In the related PHP RFC [OpenSSL AEAD support](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/openssl_aead) of January 2016, it can be read under *Future Scope*: *Adding support for OCB mode once the extension supports OpenSSL 1.1*.

Overall, it looks like OCB is in PHP probably just not fully implemented yet, just like GCM / CCM back then, and that it's a bug in the end.

Comment: As your answer would indicate would happen, I receive the "The authenticated tag cannot be provided for cipher that doesn not support AEAD" warning when attempting to use the tag. I'll just have to keep this on the back burner until the OCB implementation is complete. Thanks for digging into that for me. I would not have found that on my own.